# turf.js: Buffer executing but geojson not being added to leaflet map

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet, turfjs

div id called buffer. when user clicks on buffer the incidences points get buffered 1 mile

```
<div id="map2" class="col-md-4 well">
    <p>GeoDjango is da bomb</p>
    <button id="Highlands" class="form-control btn-primary">Highlands</button>
    <button id="buffer" class="form-control btn-warning">Buffer</button>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var incidences = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://127.0.0.1:8000/incidence_data/", {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        //console.log(feature.properties);
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name.toString())
    }
});
incidences.addTo(map);

var incidences2 = incidences.toGeoJSON();


$("#buffer").click(function () {
    if ($("#buffer").html() == 'Buffer') {
        var buff = turf.buffer(incidences2, 1, {'units': 'miles'});
        bufferLayer = L.geoJSON(buff).addTo(map);
        $("#buffer").html("Remove Buffer");
    } else {
        map.removeLayer(bufferLayer);
        $("#buffer").html("Buffer");
    }
});
```

I am not sure if the buffer is executing because there is absolutely nothing in the console.

I found this question which is eerily similar to mine. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285077/does-turf-js-work-with-geodjango

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`incidences2` should be created only AFTER `incidences` is fully loaded.

As a first check try creating it a little later:

```
console.log("starting...");

const incidences = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://127.0.0.1:8000/incidence_data/", {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        //console.log(feature.properties);
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name.toString())
    }
});
incidences.addTo(map);

console.log("... not loaded yet!");

$("#buffer").click(function () {
    const incidences2 = incidences.toGeoJSON();
    console.log(incidences2);
    if ($("#buffer").html() == 'Buffer') {
        var buff = turf.buffer(incidences2, 1, {'units': 'miles'});
        console.log(buff);
        bufferLayer = L.geoJSON(buff).addTo(map);
        $("#buffer").html("Remove Buffer");
    } else {
        map.removeLayer(bufferLayer);
        $("#buffer").html("Buffer");
    }
});
```

Comment: I think I've the same problem, but using MapBox, and I can't solve... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58771147/it-cant-possible-to-render-a-buffer-using-turf